# Difference between GKE Stackdriver Monitoring and GKE usage metering with BigQuery

Tags: monitoring, google-kubernetes-engine, stackdriver

The Google Kubernetes Engine docs have a section for [Understanding cluster resource usage](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-usage-metering) that explains how to have GKE send resource consumption data to BigQuery via the `--resource-usage-bigquery-dataset` flag.

However, there's also [Stackdriver Kubernetes Engine Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/kubernetes-engine/), which seems to accomplish the same thing, only by sending the data to Stackdriver.

Why are there two options? What are the differences between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each product has a use case.

For example, if you would like to analyze data for a [long period of time](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/management-tools/how-to-use-stackdriver-monitoring-export-for-long-term-metric-analysis). You will likely choose GKE usage metering with BigQuery because the data has no retention period unlike Stackdriver monitoring which has a 6 week [retention period](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/quotas#data_retention_policy).

In general, if you plan to [export](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/stackdriver-monitoring-metric-export) your Metric Data anywhere. You will need to pass through BigQuery.